# snapshot linux vmware guest from within vm

Tags: centos, vmware

Is it possible for a Linux VM guest to request that the host make a snapshot of itself, using just the open-vm-tools suite.  I see references that seem to indicate that it's possible, no examples.  My test environment is ESXi 5.5 and CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with open-vm-tools or vmware tools.
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Tools/12.1.0/vmware-tools-administration-guide.pdf

I believe the references to snapshots you are seeing are about the vmbackup plugin. It is not initiating the snapshot, it handles quiescing.
https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/tree/master/open-vm-tools/services/plugins/vmbackup

What you can do is freeze and clone the OS. Depending on your end goal this might work for you.
vmware-rpctool "instantclone.freeze"
vmtoolsd "instantclone.freeze"
https://williamlam.com/2018/04/new-instant-clone-architecture-in-vsphere-6-7-part-1.html

https://williamlam.com/2018/04/new-instant-clone-architecture-in-vsphere-6-7-part-2.html

Another option, but this doesn't use VMware tools, is to run something like a python script or java app from inside the guest.
https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/create_snapshot.py
https://developer.vmware.com/samples/1078/vmsnapshot?h=snapshot#

You can also use PowerCLI but it requires PowerShell to be installed on your Linux vm.
https://developer.vmware.com/docs/powercli/latest/products/vmwarevsphereandvsan/categories/snapshot/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-linux?view=powershell-7.3

I believe most backup utilities have a separate manager vm that makes the snapshots. Having another small VM to manage your snapshot tasks might be an easier route.